# How to deal with negative cost cycle error when computing shortest path with negative weights using networkx?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, shortest-path

I am using networkx to work on shortest path problems. I would like to be able to use the [shortest_path algorithm](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path) on negative weighted graph (a negative weight would indicate a gain of a specific quantity will a positive weight would indicate a consumption).

The picture on the left shows the best route when minimizing a 'length' attribute and the one on the right is the one I would like to obtain when minimizing a 'height' attribute with negative values.

[image: graph_negative weight]

When I tried to run the shortest path algorithm with the bellman-ford method (See code below), I got the error `NetworkXUnbounded: Negative cost cycle detected.`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import combinations, groupby
import os
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import random


# 1. Define test network 
MG = nx.MultiDiGraph()
MG.add_edges_from([("B", "A", {"length": 0.8}), ("A", "B", {"length": 1.}), ("D", "G", {"length": 3.5}),
                   ("B", "D", {"length": 20.8}), ("A", "C", {"length": 9.7}), ("D", "C", {"length": 0.3}),
                   ("B", "E", {"length": 4.8}), ("D", "E", {"length": 0.05}), ("C", "E", {"length": 0.1}),          
                   ("E", "C", {"length": 0.7}), ("E", "F", {"length": 0.4}), ("E", "G", {"length": 15.}),           
                   ("F", "C", {"length": 0.9}), ("F", "D", {"length": 4.}),                       
                  ])
attrs = {'B': {"x": -20., "y": 60.}, 'A': {"x": 28., "y":55.},
         'C': {"x": -12., "y": 40.}, 'D': {"x": 40., "y":45.},
         'E': {"x": 8., "y": 35.}, 'F': {"x": -8., "y":15.},    
         'G': {"x": 21., "y":5.},    
        }

for num, (k,v) in enumerate(attrs.items()):
    attrs[k]={**v,
             }  
nx.set_node_attributes(MG, attrs)

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)
random_height = list(rng.uniform(low=-100, high=100, size=len(MG.edges)).round(0))
attrs={}
for num, edge in enumerate(MG.edges):
    attrs[edge]={'height': random_height[num]}
nx.set_edge_attributes(MG, attrs)


# 2. Calculate shortest route
best_route_by_length = nx.shortest_path(MG, "A", "G",weight="length")
print(f"Best route by length: {best_route_by_length}")

best_route_by_height = nx.shortest_path(MG, "A", "G",weight="height",method='bellman-ford')
print(f"Best route by height: {best_route_by_height}")
```

Is there a way to tackle this problem (e.g. removing cycle)?

**Edit: I am looking for an optimal solution without cycles**

Comment: Can you clarify what you would consider to be a good solution?  If there is a cycle that the algorithm can follow, then you can go around that cycle a bunch of times, and keep lowering the weight of the path.  So how would you define to be the minimal path in your case to avoid this?  SO in your 2nd example, I could take a path that cycled around C->E->F a bunch of times and it would be smaller than yours.

Comment: Hi @Joel, thanks for your comment. I should have mentioned that I am looking for a solution without cycles. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to tackle this problem would be to:

1. create a copy of my graph where all the edge attributes `height` are shifted by the smallest negative value (this way all my weight are positive)
2. calculated the shortest path on this new graph

But it is not really straightforward as it requires to work on two graphs or compute additional transformations.

I attached a bit of code below showing how to compute the purple path in the original picture.

```py
import copy 

MH=copy.deepcopy(MG)

attrs={}
for num, edge in enumerate(MH.edges):
    attrs[edge] = MH.edges[edge]
    attrs[edge]['height'] += - np.min(random_height)
nx.set_node_attributes(MH, attrs)

best_route_by_height_shifted_negative = nx.shortest_path(MH, "A", "G",weight="height")
print(f"Best route by height (weight shifted by minimum negative weight): {best_route_by_height_zero_negative}")

# 3. Get stats for each route

def get_route_edge_attributes(
    G, route, attribute=None, minimize_key="length", retrieve_default=None
):
    """
    """
    attribute_values = []
    for u, v in zip(route[:-1], route[1:]):
        # if there are parallel edges between two nodes, select the one with the
        # lowest value of minimize_key
        data = min(G.get_edge_data(u, v).values(), key=lambda x: x[minimize_key])
        if attribute is None:
            attribute_value = data
        elif retrieve_default is not None:
            attribute_value = data.get(attribute, retrieve_default(u, v))
        else:
            attribute_value = data[attribute]
        attribute_values.append(attribute_value)
    return attribute_values


stats_best_route={}
stats_best_route['by_length']={'length': sum(get_route_edge_attributes(MG,
                                                                   best_route_by_length,
                                                                  'length')),
                              'height': sum(get_route_edge_attributes(MG,
                                                                   best_route_by_length,
                                                                  'height'))}
stats_best_route['by_height_with_negative']={'length': sum(get_route_edge_attributes(MG,
                                                                   best_route_by_height_shifted_negative,
                                                                  'length')),
                              'height': sum(get_route_edge_attributes(MG,
                                                                   best_route_by_height_shifted_negative,
                                                                  'height'))}

print(f"Stats best routes: {stats_best_route}")
```

```
Best route by height (weight shifted by minimum negative weight): ['A', 'C', 'E', 'G']
Stats best routes: {'by_length': {'length': 13.7, 'height': 245.0}, 'by_height_with_negative': {'length': 24.8, 'height': -70.0}}
```

Comment: This could fail - consider the edge A-B with weight 1 and then an alternate path A-C-D-B, with the first edge having weight -1/2, the second weight 0, and the third has weight 3/4.  Then the ACDB path has total weight 1/4 which is less than the A-B edge.  But if we shift everything by 1/2, then the ACDB path ends up with weight 1.75 while the A-B edge is 1.5.  So the order changes because the number of edges affects how much a path's weight is shifted.